# How to make differently indexed PHP arrays point to the same objects

Tags: php, arrays, object, reference

Within a class I have three arrays (as instance variables) that must all point to the same objects. The first is a numerically indexed array that I get back from some external function. The second array must index the same objects by their name. The third by some other property. This is for fast access via those properties. So the point is: it shouldn't matter which array I use to access an object and modify it.

Yet it can't make it happen. I know about PHP references. I know about java references. I know about C pointers, but I can't make it happen - wherever I try to place the ampersand (=&).

```
class xxx {

  private $objs;
  private $objsByName;

  public function __construct() {

    $this->objs = getObjs();
    $this->objsByName = array();
    foreach($this->objs as $obj) {
      $this->objsByName[$obj->getName()] = $obj;
    }
  }

}
```

There is no place here where I have not tried replacing = with =&

I am missing something?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You can format source code with the `{}` toolbar button (I've done it for you this time). Don't forget to tag as *Accepted* the best answer that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your foreach loop with this one.

```
for($i = 0 , $n = count($this->objs); $i < $n ; $i ++){

$this->objsByName[$this->objs[$i]->getName()] = &$this->objs[$i];

}
```

This will solve your problem :)

Thanks!

Hussain.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, objects are always passed by reference ([you cannot copy an object unless you use `clone` keyword](http://www.phpbuilder.com/manual/language.oop5.cloning.php)). This code illustrates this:

```
<?php

class AnObject{
    private $name;
    public $count=0;

    public function __construct($name){
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }
}

function getObjs(){
    return array(
        new AnObject('One'),
        new AnObject('Two'),
        new AnObject('Three'),
    );
}


class xxx {

  private $objs;
  private $objsByName;

  public function __construct() {

    $this->objs = getObjs();
    $this->objsByName = array();
    foreach($this->objs as $obj) {
      $this->objsByName[$obj->getName()] = $obj;
    }
  }

  public function alterAnObjectByName($name){
      $this->objsByName[$name]->count++;
  }

}

$x = new xxx;
var_dump($x);
$x->alterAnObjectByName('Two');
var_dump($x);
```

The issue is probably somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Mark this part from the php manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

> Unless the array is referenced, foreach operates on a copy of the specified array and not the array itself. foreach has some side effects on the array pointer. Don't rely on the array pointer during or after the foreach without resetting it.

So your $obj is a copy.

*I have not tested Hussain's code, but that looks like a good option :)*

Answer (score 0):

PHP always use copy on write functions, chances are that your objects will be same until one is changed.

To avoid errors you should say that one of your array contains the data and that thee others are just indexes.

Use the index to find the id, and use tha data array, indexed by id, to read and alter data.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP5 you can add `&` to the `as` variable to make the foreach loop not clone the object:

```
foreach($this->objs as &$obj) {
   $this->objsByName[$obj->getName()] = &$obj;
}
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

p/s: I'm not sure if the `&` inside the foreach body is needed or not but just add it to be safe. Or you can try removing it to see if it's needed or not.